# Underline removal from Custom Link onhover

Tags: css, wordpress

I just want to remove that blue underline from my donate button, its a Custom link i created after going to Appearance -> Menus -> Custom Link. The problem is this Custom link (donate button) is inheriting the same css from the navigation menu items, which i want to change. I have tried applying additional css,

```
.horizontal-navigation-bar nav ul li a:after {
  margin-bottom: -1px;                            
}
```

but no success, any help shall be appreciated.

[image]

P.S. : - (I am working for the client, he has not given public access to the website, so sharing of url will be of no use), yes i am using UltraPress theme (https://justfreethemes.com/demo/?theme=UltraPress)

thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it's just a matter of not targeting the right element, but since we can't see the code it's kind of hard to correct that.

Based on the template, this element, `ul.navbar-nav>li.menu-item>a:after`, controls the menu's underlines and the below css, **when removed**, removes the underline. So it should be something similar to this.

```
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
bottom: -3px;
height: 2px;
```

Ideally, just inspect in your dev tools to find the exact element and style.

Comment: That's true, but not working, i have added inspect detail, if you could able to identify, if i uncheck display:inline-block from a{ } element, then line gets hide, but if i copy the same class to additional css. it does not work.

Comment: Inspect the `a:after` of that element. That's the line